# Human Detection

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I want to detect people in a picture and I want to implement it without MATLAB's vision.PeopleDetector
I have the classifier and I can detect people but it detects too many people.I know I have to use **selectStrongestBbox** function and my MATLAB is r2014a and it doesn't have this function. I found its code and I implemented but the problem is that there is a function in it called : **visionBboxOverlapSuppression**
but there is no source code for this function and it doesn't work.
Does anyone have the source code of ***visionBboxOverlapSuppression*** function ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Nope, there is no source code, this is MATLAB, they own their code. Only MATLAB engineers know the source and trust me, they are not going to tell you!

Comment: Thank you @AnderBiguri
You mean only choice is to use the newer versions of MATLAB ?

Comment: Or to code it yourself, by reading research papers.

Comment: Thank you very much @AnderBiguri